# How to convert lead with specific record types using flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, record-type

Lead has record types (lets say Sales and Support) and the same record type is there for Opportunity too. When a lead is converted to Opportunity, based on the lead record type, Opportunity record type need to be set. For example, when a Sales lead is converted, it should create only Sales Opportunity. I want to achieve this scenario using salesforce FLOW.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/386222/edit) your question to add what you have tried in a Flow (it's OK if it fails) and how it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text). This site exists to *help*, not do the work. (From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*) Please read more of the Help Center, and also take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Flows don't have a Lead Convert function built in. However, you can approach this from another direction. You can set a Record Triggered Flow to run when the lead is converted, and then set any fields you want on the related Account, Contact, or Opportunity by using the ConvertedAccountId, ConvertedContactId, and/or ConvertedOpportunityId, as appropriate.